# How many essentially different generating sets of cardinality $d +1$ are there in a vector space $V$ of dim $d$ over a field of prime cardinality $p$?

Tags: combinatorics, vector-spaces, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field with $p$ elements. Let $d$ denote its dimension. For the purpose of this question let us say two subsets $A,A'$ of $V$ are equivalent if there exists an automorphism $f$ of $V$ such that $f(A)=A'$.

This notion of "equivalent" gives an equivalence relation on the set of subsets of $V$.

**Question:** What is the number of equivalence classes of generating subsets of $V$ of cardinality $d+1$?

To be precise, maybe I should say: "the  number of equivalence classes that contains some  generating subset of cardinality $d+1$." Yet, note that if a class contains one  generating subsets of cardinality $d+1$ then all sets in this class  are generating subsets of cardinality $d+1$, so ultimately different interpretations should yield the same problem.

I would be interested both in exact results as well as in estimates and/or pointers to relevant literature.

**Context:** I often need to study properties of generating subsets in finite dimensional vector space over the field with $p$ elements (think of coding theory if this at first glance seems like a strange thing to study). Usually, the properties I care about are invariant under automorphisms. Thus, in my investigations I can assume "without loss" that the set contains a specific fixed basis. Sometimes I wonder how many cases I would need to distinguish, if I would want to go one step further, and fix one element in addition to the basis.

Since so far I was always either in the case "it is easy to figure out in my current vector space" or "too many to be useful" I never investigated this seriously. Yet, I thought about it a bit and it did not seem obvious either, but maybe I just do not look at it from the right angle.

---

**Example and further comments:** Let $B= \{e_1,\dots, e_d\}$ be a basis. For $g \in V \setminus B$  the set $A_g = B \cup \{g\}$ is generating of cardinality $d+1$. It is not hard to see that each of the equivalence classes we want to count contains some set of the form $A_g$. Thus their number is bounded by $|V \setminus B|$.

But $A_g$ and $A_h$ can very well be equivalent for distinct $g,h$.

One phenomenon are permutations. If $g=\sum_{i=1}^d a_ie_i$ and $h = \sum_{i=1}^d a_{\sigma(i)}e_i$ for some permutation $\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_d$ then $A_g$ and $A_h$ are equivalent.

But this is not all. For example, let $e_0 = \sum_{i=1}^d e_i$. Then $e_1 =e_0 -   \sum_{i=2}^d e_i$, and one thus  sees that for $f_0 =e_1 -   \sum_{i=2}^d e_i$, one has $A_{e_0}$ and  $A_{f_0}$ are equivalent.

Comment: it's clearly bounded above by $p^d$ right?

Comment: Yes. If $B$ is a fixed basis then the classes of $B \cup \{g\}$ for $g \in V \setminus B$ will  yield all classes. But not all are distinct.

Comment: can you give an example of this phenomenon?

Comment: oh ok, I think I see

Comment: the permutation matrices are good examples

Comment: isn't what you want exactly the number of orbits that the permutation matrices leave on $V$?

Comment: I added some comments. Yes, permutations are important, but I do not see this is all there is to it. But I agree it is plausible this can be done via considering the right group action. But I could not do it.

Comment: thanks, it sounds interesting, I like problems on $d+1$ generating subsets. I'll try it for a while :) And sorry for cluttering your questions section. And good luck in the elections.

Comment: No problem and thanks for your interest.

Comment: Can you recall a definition of a generating subset of a vector space?

Comment: @AlexRavsky a set such that the subspace generated by the set (i.e., all linear combinations of its elements) is the full space. It will always contain a basis but might be larger. In the current case (field of prime characteristic) it coincides with 'the additive subgroup generated by the set is the full additive group.' In the specific case, size dimension plus 1, it is always of the form a basis and one more element. (But different basis could be extended to the same set.)

Comment: This is an interesting question. Sorry about missing it earlier. It seems to me that with $p=2$ the answer is $d-1$. The minimal number $m$ of vectors in $A$ involved in a linear dependence relation is surely an invariant of the equivalence class. And in the case $p=2$ it seems to be straightforward to describe a linear isomorphism taking any two sets sharing this invariant to each other. All this because there is only a single non-zero coefficient :-) The number $d-1$ comes from the fact that $3\le m\le d+1$, all occuring. I don't know about the more general case.

Comment: And, yes, you meet these kind of questions often in coding theory.

Comment: Wait! For some reason I was thinking that the zero vector is not allowed in $A$. Allowing that adds one more to the tally!

Answer (score 5):

The following observations are simple but they are too long for a coment and I allowed myself to stress them as an answer hoping that the proposed reduction may direct a way to an answer of Question.

Let $\Bbb F$ be the field with $p$ elements and $A=\{a_1,\dots, a_{d+1}\}$ be a generating subset of $V=\Bbb F^d$ of cardinality $d+1$. Then the set $A$ is linearly dependent, that is there exists a non-zero annulating vector $x=(x_1,\dots, x_{d+1})\in \Bbb F^{d+1}$, that is $\sum x_ia_i=0$. Since the set $A$ contains a basis, the vector $x$ is defined uniquely up to a multipliction by a non-zero scalar of $\Bbb F$. Moreover, if $f$ is an arbitrary automorphism of $V $ then $\sum x_if(a_i)=0$, so $f$ preserves the annulating vector of a generating set (up to a permutation of its coordinates).

Conversely, let $x\in \Bbb F^{d+1}$ be a non-zero vector. Without loss of generality, after a multipliction by a non-zero scalar and 
a permutation of coordinates, we may suppose that $x_{d+1}=1$. Given a basis $a_1,\dots, a_d$ in $V$ if we put $a_{d+1}=-\sum x_ia_i$, then we obtain a generaring set $A=\{a_1,\dots, a_{d+1}\}$ with the annualting vector $x$.

Thus the number of equivalence classes of generating subsets of $V$ of cardinality $d+1$ equals the number of equivalence classes of non-zero vectors of $\Bbb F^{d+1}$ with respect to a multipliction by a non-zero scalar and a permutation of coordinates.

This allows us to calculate the required number for small $p$. If $p=2$ then the vector equivalence class is uniquely determined by the number $n_0$ of its zero coordinates, which is from $0$ to $d$. That is in this case the answer is $d+1$. If $p=3$ then the vector equivalence class is uniquely determined by the number $n_0\le d$ of its zero coordinates and the size $\lceil(d+1-n_0)/2\rceil\le n_1\le d+1-n_0$ of the non-smaller group of its non-zero coordinates. That is in this case the answer is $\sum_{n_0=0}^d \lfloor (d+3-n_0)/2\rfloor$. This experssion equals $(d^2+6d+4)/4$ if $d$, is even and equals $(d^2+6d+5)/4$, if $d$ is odd.

Comment: Developing nicely the way I started thinking about it (+1). But I got $d-1$ as the answer in the case $p=2$?

Comment: I now realize that I forgot about the possibility of $A$ containing the zero vector. But I think that in the case $p=2$ the possibility $n_0=1$ cannot occur for then there would be two identical vectors in $A$, and it would have cardinality $d$ as opposed to $d+1$.

Comment: To go by the vector that annihilates is a nice idea, which I had not considered. I feel it makes the problem more 'symmetric' and approachable. Thanks for sharing it. Also thanks to @Jyrki for the input.